# What are the ways to get a chain of SSL certificates by URL?

Tags: android, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I need get chain of SSL certificate by URL in my android app.
Sometimes I get all chain and that's OK. But sometimes I get only two certificates in chain without root.

My actions:

- I get first cert
- I find link on next cert in  "Authority Information Access: CA Issuers - URI" field
- I get next cert by this link. And there are no field "CA Issuers - URI" in this cert.

So I can't find link on the root cert.
For example I use URL - yahoo.com

This is chain of certificates of this URL:

[image]

This is filed in second certificate in chain which I get:

[image: This]

I haven't link to the root cert.

And this parameters of response from server:

[image]

Also only two certificates.

How could I get root cerificate? Is it any another way to do this?

Comment: This is not a problem specific to android. Certificates simply are not required to have a `CA issuers - URI` information - and thus not all have one. Why do you want to get the certificate chain this way in the first place, i.e. what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? If you try to verify the server certificate for a SSL connection - that's not the way it should be done.

Comment: Yes, I've just written about instruments I'd used. Yes, I want to verify the server's certificates for the SSL connection. What way would you adviсe for this?

Comment: The root CA has to be available in the __local__ trust store and the server is supposed to send the server certificate and all intermediate certificates necessary to build the trust chain to the root CA. The TLS stack will do all the verification automatically by default. The main point is that one only trusts the __local__ trust store and does not blindly download any new root certificates from the internet. If this would be done then man in the middle attacks would be trivial.

Comment: I have two questions:
 
1. If I need add root certificate to my local storage, I would be get it somwhere, right? Must I do this manually from browser?

2. If I don't know in advance wich URLs I will be check? What should I do in this case?

This case is not real, but rather experimental. So I don't think about MITM attack etc.
I just want get all chain by URL and work with it. I have little expirience in this theme. So I will be glad if you say me a way to do what I want, or say that it is impossible. May be I find this to no purpose and don't understand this.

Comment: Public reachable servers on the internet use almost always certificates which are issued by a publicly trusted CA, which is already in the local trust store. Without this it would simply not work. But if you really want to have a different one: OS and/or browsers have mechanisms to add additional trusted root CA, details depend on the actual platform though.